# import kml file into R

Tags: r, rgdal

I'm new to the spatial side of R and trying to import a kmz file from Google Earth.  I opened the file in Google Earth and saved it as a kml file.

[image]

However, in R, I get the following error:

```
land <- readOGR("shape files/FGPcanada_landcover_2015_en.kml")
Error in ogrListLayers(dsn = dsn) : Cannot open data source
```

Comment: This question seems similar:https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/58160/134058

Comment: @Mxblsdl looks like I might need to define the layer, but I'm not sure what that is or how to find it.

Comment: Did you try reading the kml as a text file? It should have the layer info in there. Just open it from the file explorer in RStudio.

Comment: @Mxblsdl I'm a little confused.  do you mean something like: land.table <- read.table("shape files/FGPcanada_landcover_2015_en.kml")?  If so, I get this error message: Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 5 elements

Comment: find the .kml with the RStudio file explorer tab. Then just click the KML from RStudio interface. The file will open as a text file in the source panel.